# Delete/remove column with dplyr/magrittr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I remove a column with dplyr/magrittr in R?

Here I want to delete columns which have more than 50% NAs (this does not work of course):

```
delNAcols <- function(x){ ifelse( mean(is.na(x))>0.5, NULL, x ) }
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,NA),y=c(NA,NA,4))
d %>% mutate_each(funs(delNAcols))
```

## Solution

Both answers (from user3949008 and akrun) are good.

If the processing is at the beginning of the low, one could use a combination of both answers, due to the best balance of shortness and magrittr-style, in other words, best readability:

```
d %>%
  sapply(function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.5) %>% 
  extract(d,. )
```

Because of the reuse of `d` this does not work if its later in the flow. Then user3949008's answer can be used after small change (and a small readability improvement):

```
d %>% select_(.dots = names(.)[which(sapply(., function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.5))])
```

If one wants to have the whole thing even more concise, one can write

```
select_each <- function(df, fun) { df %>% sapply(fun) %>% extract(df,.) }
select_each <- function(df, fun) { df %>% select_(.dots = names(.)[which(sapply(., fun))]) }

d %>%
  select_each( function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.5 )
```

with both `select_each` function being equal in functionality. However, I benchmarked them and the first one is three times as fast.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question. If you want to answer your own question that's fine, but do it as an *answer*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) mean(is.na(x)) <= 0.5, d)
```

Or if we need to use the `flow`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
d %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean(is.na(.)) <= 0.5)) %>% 
   unlist %>% 
   extract(d,. )
```

Comment: I am using longer processing flows. I would like to add the functionality into the flow, that's why mentioned dplyr. magrittr would be okay of course as well.

Comment: @Make42 Updated the post

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing it right now. You can make your code easier to understand by writing `mean(is.na(,))<0.5` instead of `sum(is.na(.)) <= length(.)/2`.

Comment: Why does it give me the error without `unlist`, but `class(d %>% summarise_each(funs(delNAcols)))` results in `data.frame`?

Comment: @Make42  Because `data.frame` is a `list` with elements of equal length.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it - using select_ (because we will be supplying names to select as character vector):

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,NA), y = c(NA,NA,4), z = c(1,2,3), a = c(NA,NA,2), b = c(1,NA,2))
select_(d, .dots = names(d)[which(sapply(d, function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.5))])
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by writing `function(x) mean(is.na(x))<0.5`  instead of `function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) > 0.5) == FALSE)`.

Comment: I just noticed: This does not work for `d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,NA),y=c(NA,NA,4),z=c(1,NA,2))`

Comment: This is starting to have very low readability. Can we improve on that?